# Datastore cluster with vCenter and 2 VMFS datastores

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I have a vCenter setup with 2 esxi hosts.
Both hosts (dedicated servers) have their own datastore (vmfs) connected to their harddrives.

I'd now like to setup a datastore cluster, however the setup is complaining about both hosts not being able to see each other's datastore.

Is there a way I can mount both datastores so that both hosts can access it? Or do I need a separate dedicated server with its own harddrive and share it across the network (nfs)?

Comment: What VMware license level do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datastore clustering is a feature intended for use with [Storage DRS](http://www.vmware.com/products/datacenter-virtualization/vsphere/storage-drs.html). All hosts need to be able to see al datastores in a datastore cluster. What you're doing with local disk is not compatible.

*Note the "All Hosts Connected" status below...*
[image]

Comment: Ok, so I should set up an NFS server to achieve what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Or a iSCSI server or any other way to let think your hosts that drives are network attached devices.

StorageDRS and Datastores aggregate are not allowed for local hard drive.